# What would you call someone who continues to be the "first one" to achieve something?

Tags: expressions, writing

I want to write a sentence which tells someone is continuing to "be the first one to do/achieve whatever" and keeps breaking records.

For example, there's a singer in my country who became the first one to succeed in the US music industry, first to hold a concert in  another country, first to win a certain prize... and so on.

> She is continuing to earn a "first-ever" title.
>
> She is continuing to add a first-ever title to her career.

Do these sound natural to you or would you recommend me a better expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not say that *first-ever title* is altogether natural.

Instead, I would use the word [**pioneer**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pioneer):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   *noun*
>   **2 a** :  a person or group that originates or helps open up a new line of thought or activity or a new method or technical development
>
> *verb*
>   **1** : to open or prepare for others to follow also : SETTLE
>   **2**: to originate or take part in the development of

So:

> She continues to be a *pioneer* [in her career / field].

Note that this implies nobody else has done what she's done; it's not just firsts for her, but for anyone. That doesn't necessarily match the example sentences, but it does match the description given in the question.

---

In the right context, you could also say:

> She is continuing to break records.
>   She is continuing to be the first to . . .